# Getting a list of attachments from RavenDB 2.5

Tags: ravendb, blobstore

I'm storing several attachments in ravenDB 2.5 and I would like to retrieve not only one attachment by some specific keyname but I want to get a list of all attachments. What I tried to do is to get attachments by the following code sample:

```
dbCommands.GetAttachmentHeadersStartingWith("keyname/", 0, 100);
```

But as expected this will return only the attachment headers (metadata) and no attachment data. 
Is there a solution to achieve this task?

I know ravenDB 3.0 is coming with a blob store, but as it is unstable at the moment, I dont want to use it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to download each attachment individually.